# My window doesn't display when I call .Show()

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this window defined in C#:

```xaml
<Window x:Class="VirginOneAccount.AccountInfo"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Account Information" Height="362" Width="614" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="AccountTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=AccountName}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="418*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="174*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="40,16,42,0" Name="AccountsList" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
      ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AccountTemplate}" AllowDrop="False" DataContext="{Binding}" IsEnabled="True" SelectionChanged="AccountsList_SelectionChanged" />
    <Button Content="Save Changes" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40,0,0,10" Name="saveChanges" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="90" IsEnabled="False" Click="saveChanges_Click" />
</Grid>
```

Then in the main form, I call `Show()` on an instance of the window:

```
AccountInfo Accounts = new AccountInfo();
Accounts.Show();
```

But all I see is an empty window (not even the right size). Why isn't it opening *my* window?

Comment: Are you sure that your program is compiling correctly?  Try doing a clean build- Ctrl+Shift+B

Comment: As an aside, those are some interesting ColumnDefinition ratios.

Comment: Is the line Accounts.Show() definitely being executed?

Comment: Yes it compiles ok.
yes the .Show() call executes
A window displays but not the one I am expecting.
I don't know what ColumnDefinition ratios means

Comment: Is the line `Accounts.SHow()` AFTER the `InitializeComponents()` ?

Comment: Please give us context of your csharp code. We see 2 lines of it, but it doesn't really tell us what's going on.  Strip the sensitive and irrelevant code from the class and upload it as a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/) and link to that or something.

Comment: You need to set the DataContext before the show call for the {Binding} to have any effect. That's not in your example. You should also set the Owner/Parent property on the Window before the show call.

Answer (score 1):

I did a simple window and this worked for me.  Take it down to just a textbox and see if it works.

```
public MainWindow()
{   
    InitializeComponent();

    Window1 win1 = new Window1();
    win1.Show();            
}
```

Comment: That's it thanks!
No    InitializeComponent();  call in the constructor

Answer (score 0):

The window class name may be different between the xaml definition and the code behind file. 
Example

```
telerik:RadWindow x:Class="MyWindow"
vs 

    public partial class My_Window : RadWindow
    {
        public My_Window()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

In this case the `initializeComponent()` call is unrecognized by the compiler